# How do I select every second face?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces, topology

Now I'm making quite a lot of gears (I know there is an add-on for that) and I would like to speed up the process. There are many ways of a selection, but I would like to know in which situations <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> works.

Is there a way to select one face out of two?

[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "Also is there a way to allocate through one"? If you're trying to select one face out of two, select all the face ring then Select > Checker Deselect?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks a lot <3

Comment: In which situations Shift+R works? Well, it is the shortcut for _Repeat Last Action_ so it usually works on every last action you've done in the _3D Viewport_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the face ring (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right Click</kbd>) then *Select > Checker Deselect* (then you can set some parameters in the *Operator Box* if needed, for example you can select 1 face out of 3, etc):

[image]